# Sufficient statistics of independent r.v(Check solution)

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics

Let $P = (f_{\theta} :\theta \in \Theta)$

Suppose we have $X_1$ and $X_2$ iid with density: $f_{\theta} = \theta * x^{\theta - 1}$ ( $ x\in [0,1]$)

I want to show, that $T(X_1,X_2)$ is sufficient for $P$  where $T(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$

Definition of sufficient statistic: $f(x|T(x)) =  \frac{f_p^x(x)}{f_p^T(T(x))} = \frac{\theta X_1^{\theta - 1} \theta X_2^{\theta - 1}}{\theta^2 t^{\theta - 1}} = \frac{\theta^2 (X_1X_2)^{\theta - 1}}{\theta^2 t^{\theta - 1}} = \frac{\theta^2 t^{\theta - 1}}{{\theta^2 t^{\theta - 1}}} = 1$

But I doubt in my calculations,because I am not sure, if I defined my T(X) in denominator correctly.

Is it correct? If not, please tell me, what should I improve

Edit:

$f(x|T(x)) =  \frac{f_p^x(x)}{f_p^T(T(x))} = \frac{\theta X_1^{\theta - 1} \theta X_2^{\theta - 1}}{\theta t^{\theta - 1}} = \frac{\theta^2 (X_1X_2)^{\theta - 1}}{\theta t^{\theta - 1}} = \frac{\theta^2 t^{\theta - 1}}{{\theta t^{\theta - 1}}} = \theta $

Comment: $f_\theta$ is not a valid density.  Are you perhaps assuming the density is zero except for $0\lt x \le 1$?  If that's the case, consider working with the logarithms $Y_i=-\log(X_i)$ of the variables instead: they have very nice distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
The joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2)' = (X_1X_2, X_2)'$ is 
$$
\theta^2 y_1^{\theta-1}, \hspace{10mm} 0 < y_1 < y_2 < 1.
$$

The density of the product is different. You need to compute
$$
f_{Y_1}(y_1) = \int_{y_1}^1 \theta^2 y_1^{\theta-1} dy_2.
$$
The result of this should be your denominator.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But how did you get the last integral?

Comment: Because the formula of density of product seems to be different

Comment: @vitsuk yeah that's my point. I used the transformation theorem to find the joint density, then I integrated out the undesired variable to find the marginal. Note the support is not a rectangle.

Comment: And how did you integrate out the variable y?

Comment: EDIT:
$$
P(Y\leq y)= P(X_1X_2\leq y) = \int_0^1 \theta P(X_1\leq y/x) x^{\theta - 1} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\theta}{x}y^{\theta}, dx
$$

Density is derivative, so:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{-\theta y^{\theta}}{x^2} dx$$

Comment: @vitsuk the density for the product $Y_1 = X_1X_2$ should be $f_{Y_1}(y_1) = \theta^2y_1^{\theta-1}(1-y_1)$.

Comment: Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: @vitsuk I don't think you took the derivative with respect to $y$ correctly. Also I don't think the CDF is correct

Comment: Agree: now I got: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\theta^2}{x}  y^{\theta -1 } dx$$ But right now I have x.